# The style api is not working in antd modals

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

style={{ top: '20' }} - this does not seems to be working.What should i do. All other antd features are working.

```
const LoginModal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
    //const [form] = Form.useForm();
    const onFinish = (values) => {
      console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    };

return (

<Modal
  title="Sign In"
  **style={{ top: '20' }}**
  visible={showModal}
  onCancel={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
  width={500}
>

  <h1>Welcome Back !</h1>
 <Form
  name="normal_login"
  className="login-form"
  initialValues={{
    remember: true,
  }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this Style**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
modalStyle:{
      marginTop:theme.Spacing(5);
           }
}));

const classes = useStyles();
return(
       className={classes.modalStyle}
       )
```